# Aligning scale of map in QGIS print layout to extent of region of interest

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents, scale

I am quite new to QGIS and have managed to create a raster map with some additional labels. But when I want to export the map with some additional text, using Print Layout, the map gets "scaled". I have a feeling the "Add map" uses the dimensions from current view in QGIS.

Is there any way to align the "Add map" with the actual dimensions of the map?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a polygon layer to define the extent of the map you want to show in the print layout:

1. Create a new polygon layer in main QGIS window and draw one polygon that covers the extent you want to show on the printed map. Alternatively, use any of your layers that have the extent you want.
2. In the print layout, go to the map's `Item Properties`, define the X/Y min/max values based on the extent (x_min/y_min and x_max/y_max) values of the polygon using data driven override with this expression

   `x_min (geometry (get_feature_by_id ('polygon',1)))`

   Adapt `x_min` accordingly and replace `polygon` with the name of the layer that defines the extent. Delete the scale so it will be calculated automatically, based on the extent you defined.

[image]